# Putting Data into MongoDB Collection Using URL Params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm currently working on a research project for my CSCI class that requires studying cyber security in great detail. Replicating what a phishing site might look like is one of the goals I've set for myself. But I'm having trouble understanding how to add information to the URL and add it to the MongoDB collection. The URL that will put the email address and password into the collection is "https://URL.com/insert?email=EMAIL@gmail.com&password=123456." I am a complete novice when it comes to creating APIs, thus I need some assistance.

I have so far made a simple form and a js file to insert the form's data into MongoDB, but I'm unable to tweak it such that it accepts parameters for URLs instead.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>To MongoDB</h1>
    <form class="container" method="post" action="/">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="password"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button>ADD</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASS>@<CLUSTER>.mongodb.net/Data", { useNewUrlParser: true}, { useUnifiedTopology: true})

const dataSchema = {
    email: String,
    password: String
} 

const Data = mongoose.model("Data", dataSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    //res.send("express is working");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})
//app.post
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    let newData = new Data({
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    newData.save();
    res.redirect("/");
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server is running on port : 3000");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the url query parameters using `req.query`.
If your URL is `https://URL.com/insert?email=EMAIL@gmail.com&password=123456`
you can access the parameters with `req.query.email` and `req.query.password`
To handle blank inputs, you have to add a check
A relevant code snippet would be:

```
app.get("/insert", function(req, res){
    if (!req.query.email || !req.query.password) {
        return res.status(400).send("failed");
    }
    let newData = new Data({
        email: req.query.email,
        password: req.query.password
    });
    newData.save();
    res.send("success");
});
```

Comment: Everything is working great, it is just whenever I call the insert function with no query params in the URL, it will input blank data into the DB. How would I stop that?

Comment: @Spencer I have updated my answer according to your query.

Comment: Thank you so much. My apologies for taking so long to answer as well. I thought I responded the day you responded but it must not have been posted.